# c# faster way to read all textboxes/labels

Tags: c#, forms, label

I have a form with buttons and labels for nine sets. Click functions for the buttons update the numbers in the label. At the end, I am saving the label values to a file. The labels have names like eLabel1, eLabel2, eLabel3.. I am using for loop wrapped around switch(case) to select and save the labels.
My question is if there is something with less lines of code for the switchcase? I was thinking of a string like "e"+i to call the label. I know there's no .GetByName() but is there something else to use? Like .FromHandle()?

Here's the short version.
I have nine labels eLabel1, eLabel2, eLabel3..

```
public void save()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
       string[] posstrings=switchpos(i+1);

       //string manipulation stuff
  }
}

    private string[] switchpos(int i)
    {

        string e;
        string[] posstrings;
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                e = eLabel1.Text;
                break;
             case 2:
             //and so on
        }

        posstrings = new string[11] { e, m, l, s, b, pfc, pfr, pf3, cf, ct, cr};
        return posstrings;
    }
```

I want to know if there is a different way to do the switch.

Comment: This is a lot of talk with no code. We're programmers, we like to read CODE.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: *I know there's no .GetByName()* ->  `this.Controls.Find("name")`

Comment: Tried this.Controls.Find() but array returned was empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array with the references to the labels:

```
Label[] labels = { eLabel1, eLabel2, eLabel3, ... };
```

Producing an array with the texts from the labels would be a one-liner:

```
string[] values = labels.Select(l => l.Text).ToArray();
```